# Where do you install django-registration-redux module?

Tags: django, django-registration

I have my own project called "polling".  I am looking to install the django-registration-redux submodule to create the log-in process.  Where should I same the Django-registration-redux module?  Another way to ask this is what does the directory structure look like?

Should I save it within the polling directory?  or on the same level as polling because it is a separate project that I'm importing?

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](https://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html):

> #### Automatic installation via a package manager
>
> Several automatic package-installation tools are available for Python; the recommended one is pip.
>
> Using pip, type:
>
> ```
> pip install django-registration-redux
> ```
>
> #### Manual installation from a downloaded package
>
> If you prefer not to use an automated package installer, you can download a copy of django-registration-redux and install it manually... From a command line in that directory, type:
>
> ```
> python setup.py install
> ```

Bottom line, just run the setup installation process and it will "install" it to the right place.

Comment: @LegoSormtroopr. I'm just trying to save it as a submodule in Github. It will ask you to save it to a local directory.  Just wondering where I should put it.